# Cppcoro not accepting result from an constom awaitable struct

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

I decided to write my own awaitable in order to loader to learn how C++ coroutine works. For now, I want to build my own struct that is equivalent to this:

```cpp
cppcoro::task<int> bar()
{
    co_yield 42;
}
```

This is what I came up after reading [CppReference's coroutine page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines). Which states *Finally, awaiter.await_resume() is called, and its result is the result of the whole co_await expr expression.* I assume that changing the return type of `await_resume()` is enough to gave both `bar` and  `make_awaitable` the same functionality.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <coroutine>
#include <cppcoro/task.hpp>
#include <cppcoro/sync_wait.hpp>

auto make_awaitable() {
    using return_type = int;
    struct awaitable {
        bool await_ready() {return false;}
        void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> h) {
            std::cout << "In await_suspend()" << std::endl;
            h.resume();
        }
        int await_resume() {return 42;};
        
    };
    return awaitable{};
}

cppcoro::task<int> foo()
{
    int n = co_await make_awaitable();
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    cppcoro::sync_wait(foo());
    std::cout << "Called coro" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But running the code generates an assertion error.

```
coro_test: /usr/include/cppcoro/task.hpp:187: cppcoro::detail::task_promise<T>::rvalue_type cppcoro::detail::task_promise<T>::result() && [with T = int; cppcoro::detail::task_promise<T>::rvalue_type = int]: Assertion `m_resultType == result_type::value' failed.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Compiler: GCC 10

Comment: I also have a coroutine library, [concurrencpp](https://github.com/David-Haim/concurrencpp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, I think, that you declared your return type as `task<int>` but you don't actually `co_return` any `int`.

Does the problem go away if you `co_return` n?